# Windows kernel debugging with windbg through network: is there an alternative to ".kdfiles"?

Tags: windbg, windows-kernel

I have a Windows kernel driver `mydriver`, which is involved in the Windows boot sequence. I run windbg on a host machine to debug the target machine. My target machine, which runs the driver, is a Windows 11 virtual machine. I can control it using a virtual manager.

The driver doesn't control anything critical about the boot process; it's somewhere in the boot sequence just because that's how we do it (I am not an expert). I don't have `bootdebug ON`.

I use windbg with the following workflow:

1. Compile my driver; the result is `mydriver.sys`
2. Copy `mydriver.sys` to `c:\temp`
3. In windbg, run the command `.kdfiles mydriver.sys c:\temp\mydriver.sys`
4. Reboot the Windows virtual machine which I am debugging
5. Windbg sends the updated compiled driver, printing `.....` for progress
6. Observe how the new driver behaves

Sometimes (that is to say, 75% of the time), the progress at step 5 stops for no apparent reason. Windbg waits several minutes and reports that the target VM crashed.

```
................................KDTARGET: Refreshing KD connection
Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
 
A fatal system error has occurred.
```

It looks like the process of sending the compiled driver is too delicate and not tolerant to network variability. I'd like to eliminate it.

How else can I copy the compiled driver's sys-file to my target computer, so it would be loaded at Windows boot time?

Comment: I suppose you've already checked the [Mapping Driver Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/mapping-driver-files) help (and notably the part about boot drivers)? It's a bit hard to know if this still applies to your case, since we don't where your driver is located in the boot sequence. Could you give a bit more information about your test lab: where is your driver located in the boot sequence? is the target a VM or a physical computer? is it available physically or at the other end of the world? Are you debugging at the boot (`bootdebug ON`) and other info.

Comment: Yes, I have checked Mapping Driver Files — it uses the `.kdfiles` command; this is the only thing I have checked. I am looking for another way to do the same, which doesn't involve moving files through network.